# Predict linearRidge with dummy variable

Tags: r, regression, prediction, dummy-data

I am trying to do a ridge regression using the codes below with GenCont data in the library `ridge`

```
library(ridge)
data(GenCont)
GenCont_df <- as.data.frame(GenCont)
GenCont_df$SNP1 <- as.factor(GenCont_df$SNP1)
mod2 <- linearRidge(Phenotypes ~ SNP1+SNP2, data = GenCont_df)
predict(mod2, GenCont_df, na.action = na.pass, all.coef = FALSE,scaling ="scale")
```

But if I used dummy variables in the model I get this error

```
Error in X[, ll] : subscript out of bounds
```

Is there a way to predict dummy variables in Ridge regression in R?

Comment: It would appear ridge regression uses PCA at some point, for which categorical variables are hard to translate into metrics that can be expressed in a meaningful distance.

Comment: In that case is there a short cut in R where I can recode my dummy variables. Let say I have category A,B and C, I want to create a column for them containing 1 and 0

Comment: Nevermind, `model.matrix` seems to work

Comment: Can you Explain how you fixed the error @jbest?